# JS querySelectorAll and a regular expression as selector

Tags: javascript, regex

I wish to write something like:

```
var N = document.querySelectorAll("input[id^='left"+/^[0-9]*$/+"right']").length;
```

How do I do in JS / JQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Attribute selectors do not support regexp. You can select based on prefix and suffix, though:

```
[id^="left"][id$="right"]
```

If you want to exclude elements with IDs missing the digits in between `left` and `right`, you'll have to filter them out:

```
Array.from(queryResults).filter(elt => /^left\d*right$/.test(elt.id));
```

In general, however, using IDs with complex internal structure is often not the best approach. You will have to keep constructing them and picking them apart. Consider using classes and/or data attributes, or it's often the case that if you are creating the elements yourself, you can just remember the elements and reference them directly.

Comment: queryResults.filter(elt => elt.id.test(/^left\d*right$/)); return _error .. .filter is not a function_ (Sorry, I am missing something basic). (id's are given, I have to use them)

Comment: Try `Array.from(queryResults).filter`, or in an older environment `Array.prototype.filter.call(queryResults, filterfunc)`.

Comment: Nope, I have to go, need to check better tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I got it. Thanks so much. (Maybe you may edit your answer, as to include/explain  your comment)